# Spark: keyBy() vs mapToPair()

Tags: java, apache-spark

In Java Spark, I could use either keyBy() or mapToPair() to create some key for a JavaRDD. Using keyBy() makes my intentions more clear and takes an argument function with a bit less code (the function returns a key rather than a tuple). However is there any improvement in performance in using keyBy() over mapToPair()? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can browse the difference in the source:

```
def mapToPair[K2, V2](f: PairFunction[T, K2, V2]): JavaPairRDD[K2, V2] = {
  def cm: ClassTag[(K2, V2)] = implicitly[ClassTag[(K2, V2)]]
  new JavaPairRDD(rdd.map[(K2, V2)](f)(cm))(fakeClassTag[K2], fakeClassTag[V2])
}
```

And:

```
def keyBy[U](f: JFunction[T, U]): JavaPairRDD[U, T] = {
  implicit val ctag: ClassTag[U] = fakeClassTag
  JavaPairRDD.fromRDD(rdd.keyBy(f))
}
```

Which calls:

```
def keyBy[K](f: T => K): RDD[(K, T)] = withScope {
    val cleanedF = sc.clean(f)
    map(x => (cleanedF(x), x))
}
```

They basically both call `map` and generate a new `RDD`. I see no significant differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not related to performance, one difference is that in case of `mapToPair` you can transform the VALUE according to your needs, which is not possible in case of `keyBy`.

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, String> deptIdEmployeeRecordRDD = empRDD.keyBy(record ->record.split(",")[5]); 
// you can only return the key, index 5 is the department Id, the intention here is to join with department rdd below
```

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, String> deptIdDeptRecordRDD = deptRDD.mapToPair(record -> {
    int firstCommaIndex = record.indexOf(",");
    String value = record.substring(firstCommaIndex+1);
    String key = record.substring(0, firstCommaIndex);
    return new Tuple2<>(key, value);
}); //returning both key and value, removing the "deptId" from the value part
```